# Why are my PRs being auto-closed?

Tags: github, github-api, github3.py

My company is using github enterprise and I am using github3.py API to automatically create pull requests.

I have code as follows:

```
detailed = "%s: Auto Pull Request from '%s' %s" % (base, from_branch, custom_message)
pr = repo.create_pull(description, base, from_branch, detailed)
```

After I create the PR, for some reason it's been automatically closed. If I just call reopen immediately after creating it, it doesn't work as well. If I `time.sleep(3)` and try to reopen it, it works.

I have just 1 thread executing and checking the logs, the API calls seems to be synchronous, they return a response first and only them the next URL is called.

Before creating the PR, I am deleting the base branch and creating it again from master, not sure if it could be related.

Is there any obvious reason I am missing here? Should this be working?

Comment: What do you do after `pr = repo.create_pull(...)`? Have you contacted GitHub support about this?

Comment: I do nothing, and it got closed. I will try to contact the support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly you might be deleting the branch that the pull request is based on. I tested this workflow just now for the first time and indeed   the PR was closed ([PR here](https://github.com/bitoiu/svn-test/pull/2)):

[image]

Notice that I've deleted the branch first and that closed the PR, although the notifications are in the reverse order for this particular corner case.

Is this what you experience as well?

Comment: Exactly, I have deleted the branch, re-created the branch again and then I created the PR. The PR was closed.

Comment: It seems (I can't be sure) in github server there is some kind of parallelism making this happen, it seems the call returns before the operation completes entirely.

Comment: start with not deleting the base. I'm recommending this because it's usually not a workflow a human would conduct. I do understand why you might do it, but I recommend not to, in order to first find out if this is the root cause.